# Llamar una función que está dentro en un addEventListener

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy utilizando JS para hacer los procesos en segundo plano y que el usuario no tenga que recargar la página para ver los procesos que realizó.

De esta manera he conseguido hacer a través de el `addEventListener` comenzar un proceso de búsqueda, utilizando `ajax` hago dicho proceso, pero tratando de recargar nuevamente los datos que están sin procesar resulta que no se actualiza la tabla, pues no he podido dar con la solución al problema.

Lo tengo en un archivo js de la siguiente manera:

```
//ME TRAE LAS MATERIAS (CICLO - DEP) QUE NO HAN SIDO CARGADAS
var mate = [];
document.getElementById("btn_buscar").addEventListener("click", function () {

var ciclo = $('#ciclo_esc').val();
var depe = $('#depe').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '../administrador/config/select/mate_depeciclo.php' + `?ciclo=${ciclo}&depe=${depe}`,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data,status) {
        mate = data;
        llenarTablaMaterias();
   
            },
    error: function (data, status) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
        mate = data;
        llenarTablaMaterias();
    }
});
})

function llenarTablaMaterias() {
document.querySelector('#tabla_materias tbody').innerHTML = '<tr> </tr>';
for (let i = 0; i < mate.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('#tabla_materias tbody').innerHTML +=
        `
    <tr class='check'>
        <td>
        ${i+1}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate[i].asignatura}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate[i].semestre}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate[i].grupo}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate[i].subgrupo}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate[i].hrs_t}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate[i].hrs_p}
        </td>   
        <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="añadir(${mate[i].id})" class="btn btn-outline-success">
            Añadir
        </button>
        </td>   
    </tr>
    `
}
}
 //ME TRAE LAS MATERIAS ASIGNADAS AL DOCENTE SELECCIONADO
 var docente = document.getElementById('docente');
 var mate_asig = [];
document.getElementById('btn_buscar').addEventListener('click', function () {

var ciclo = $('#ciclo_esc').val();
var depe = $('#depe').val();

docente.addEventListener('change', async function () {
    var doc = $('#doc').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '../administrador/config/mate_asig_doc.php' + `?ciclo=${ciclo}&depe=${depe}&doc=${doc}`,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            mate_asig = data;
            console.log(status);
            llenarTablaMateAsig();
        },
        error:function(data,status){
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        }
    })

});
})

function llenarTablaMateAsig() {
document.querySelector('#tabla_materias_asig tbody').innerHTML = '';
for (let i = 0; i < mate_asig.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('#tabla_materias_asig tbody').innerHTML +=
        `
    <tr class='check'>
       <td>${i+1}</td>
        <td>
            ${mate_asig[i].asignatura}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate_asig[i].semestre}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate_asig[i].grupo}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate_asig[i].subgrupo}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate_asig[i].hrs_t}
        </td>
        <td>
            ${mate_asig[i].hrs_p}
        </td>   
        <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="retirar(${mate_asig[i].id})" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
            Retirar
        </button>
        </td>  
    </tr>
    `
}
}

function retirar(index){
var doc = $('#doc').val();
const asig = index;
var datosEnviar = JSON.stringify({ doc:doc, id:asig})
$.ajax({
    url: '../administrador/config/asig_excel.php',
    type:'DELETE',
    data:datosEnviar,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        llenarTablaMateAsig();
        llenarTablaMaterias();
       
    },
    error:function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        llenarTablaMateAsig();
        llenarTablaMaterias();
    }
})
}

function añadir (index){
var doc = $('#doc').val();
const asig = index;
var datosEnviar = JSON.stringify({ doc:doc, id:asig});

$.ajax({
    url: '../administrador/config/asig_excel.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:datosEnviar,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
       
    },
    error:function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        llenarTablaMateAsig();
        llenarTablaMaterias();
    }
})
}
```

En este punto las funciones añadir() y retirar() funcionan adecuadamente, sin embargo, el problema continua pues, no se recargan las tablas en donde se encuentran dichas materias, de antemano les agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Define la función por fuera de la declaración del listener con eso: a) el listener simplemente invoca la función, y b) la puedes llamar desde otro lugar en tu programa

Comment: seria algo como:
    function prueba(){
     //procesos
    }
addeventlistener('click',  ***prueba()***  )